# Update database, android

Tags: android

I've created a method to update an entry to the database within my android application.

```
 public int updateEntryById(ContentValues diaryValues) {

    String  updateWhere = Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID;
    Log.i(TAG, "UpdateWhere query values" + updateWhere);
    SQLiteDatabase db = diaryDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();

    updateValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE, "");
    updateValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_DATE, "");
    updateValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TIME, "");
    updateValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_ENTRY, "");
    updateValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_LAT, "");
    updateValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_LONG, "");

    Log.i(TAG, "UPDATE" + updateWhere);
    //performs the update
    int count = db.update(
            Diary.DiaryItem.TABLE_NAME, 
            updateValues, 
            updateWhere, 
            null);

    return count;
}
```

A problem I am finding is that the Log.i(TAG, "UpdateWhere query values" + updateWhere); Doesn't actually give the ID rather the _ID = _ID, which is the column name. instead I want it to be where _ID = 1 for example.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
protected void saveDiaryItem() {
        ContentValues saveValues = new ContentValues();

        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID, mID.getText().toString());
        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE, mTitle.getText().toString());
        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_DATE, mDate.getText().toString());
        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TIME, mTime.getText().toString());
        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_ENTRY, mEntry.getText().toString());
        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_LAT, mLat.getText().toString());
        saveValues.put(Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_LONG, mLong.getText().toString());

        Log.i(TAG, "About to insert data" + saveValues);
        DAO diarySave = new DAO(getBaseContext());

        diarySave.updateEntryById(saveValues);
        Log.i(TAG, "IM BACK!"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is `updateEntryById`, but you don't pass any ID. 
Do you know which id you want to update?

Currently you have this line

```
String  updateWhere = Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID;
```

which put `Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID;` on both sides of the '=' wign, so you can't expect to get a proper id value.

Shouldn't you get this id as argument of your function?

```
public int updateEntryById(ContentValues diaryValues, int id)
```

It also seems that you don't use the arg `ContentValues diaryValues`
It it normal?

Comment: I have passed the ID within the contentvalues from my entry class *posted code above*, so shouldn't that work?

Comment: But you never use the "diaryValues" variable. If the id is inside, you should write `String  updateWhere = Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + diaryValues.id;`